# Custom Many-To-Many relation in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I want to implement the following entities in Doctrine:

[image]

`Thing` represents anything that can perform an action over another `Thing`. A `Relation` can contain two entities and a description of the action, and its tuple is unique.

Here are some examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

- Hens (thing) lay (action) eggs (thing)
- Water (thing) extinguishes (action) fire (thing)
- Bob (thing) likes (action) apples (thing)
- Bob (thing) drinks (action) water (thing)

As you can see, order matters (it's not the same "Bob likes apples" as "Apples like Bob").

---

Despite my best efforts, I can't find any proper way to implement this.

I've tried creating a field called `$relations` in `Thing` tagged as "One-To-Many" and then marking `$left` and `$right` in `Relation` as "Many-To-One". The problem is I can't have two inversed sides for the same owning side (at least AFAIK).

This current implementation neither allows for getting all relations for a particular `Thing` in the `$relations` field as I'm only able to specify one inversed side.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Thing {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   */
  protected $id;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
  protected $name;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Relation", mappedBy="right")
   */
  protected $relations;
}


/** @ORM\Entity */
class Relation {
  /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="string") */
  protected $action;

  /** @ORM\Id @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thing") */
  private $left;

  /** @ORM\Id @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thing", inversedBy="relations") */
  private $right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Doctrine doesn't directly allow for this kind of relation.

The best solution I could came up with was to create two collections in `Thing` for the relations instead of one and then defining a method that outputs both:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Thing {
  // [...]

  /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Relation", mappedBy="left") */
  protected $relationsLeft;

  /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Relation", mappedBy="right") */
  protected $relationsRight;

  public function getRelations() {
    return new ArrayCollection(array_merge(
      $this->relationsLeft->toArray(),
      $this->relationsRight->toArray()
    ));
  }
}


/** @ORM\Entity */
class Relation {
  // [...]

  /** @ORM\Id @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thing", inversedBy="relationsLeft") */
  private $left;

  /** @ORM\Id @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thing", inversedBy="relationsRight") */
  private $right;
}
```